# Best server configuration for site with heavy calculations

Tags: python, nginx, apache2, server, uwsgi

I have a site, that performs some heavy calculations, using library for symbolic math.

Currently average calculation time is 5 seconds.

I know, that ask too broad question, but nevertheless, what is the optimized configuration for this type of sites? What server is best for this?

Currently, I'm using Apache with mod_wsgi, but I don't know how to correctly configure it.

On average site is receiving 40 requests per second.

How many processes, threads, MaxClients etc. should I set?

Maybe, it is better to use nginx/uwsgi/gunicorn (I'm using python as programming language)?

Anyway, any info is highly appreciated.

Comment: Heavy calculations would benefit from movement to a compiled language (C variant/Go/Java/Scala).  For deployment purposes, I'd recommend Go for it's concurrency and compilation to a single binary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew,

I believe that you can move some pieces of your deployment topology.

My suggestion is use nginx for delivering HTTP content, and expose your application using some web framework, i.e. tornadoweb (my preference, considering async core, and best documented if compared to twisted, even twisted being a really great framework)

You can communicate between nginx and tornado by proxy. It is simple to be configured.

You can replicate your service instance to distribute your calculation application inside the same machine and another hosts. It can be easily configured by nginx upstreams.

If you need more performance, you can break your application in small modules and integrate it using Async Messaging. You can choose using zeromq or rabbitmq, among other solutions.

Then, you can have different topologies, gradually applied during the evolution of your application.

1th Topology:
nginx -> tornadoweb

2th Topology:
nginx with loadbalance (upstreams) -> tornadoweb replicated on [1..n] instances

3rd Topology:

[2nd topology] -> your app integrated by messaging (zeromq, amqp(rabbitmq), ...)

My favorite is 3rd, for begining. But, you should start, for this moment, by 1th and 2nd

There are a lot of options. But, these thre may be sufficient for a simple organization of your app.